# How to get data from AngularFirestore's valueChanges()

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following code

```
public getFullUserData(): User {
const userRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<any> = this.afs.doc(
  `users/${this.authState.uid}`);
return userRef.valueChanges().pipe(map((user: User) => user));
}
```

What am I trying to achieve is to get User object out of the observable and return that in this function...

To be exact i want to return strict data not observable of data. 
Is that even possible? 
Or should I return observables and subscribe to them later?

I know that I've made some kind of basic mistake, but I'm totally lost now...

Can someone explain how to achieve that?
I'm using this method in the service just to call it later in other components...

Comment: If you want to return value which you get from observable. I think you should return observable then subscribe to it. Because your function is not gonna wait for observable to emit value. Correct me if i'm wrong and if possible share ex of your code on stackblitz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate them.

```
const userRef: AngularFirestoreDocument = this.afs.doc(users/${user.uid});

userRef.valueChanges().subscribe(res=>{
    if(res){
       // work with data here
    }
});
```

I think you want to get the user out of the method without subscribing but I'm not sure I follow you.

```
this.afs.doc(users/${user.uid}).valueChanges().pipe(
    take(1)
).subscribe(data => {
    // work with data here
});
```

Maybe you want a function that makes a call and return the user without spending time on subscriptions?

```
function returnUser():user {
    this.afs.doc(users/${user.uid}).valueChanges().pipe(take(1)).subscribe(user => {
        return user;
    });
}
```

`take(1)` will wait until it gets the first response then unsubscribe. No observable maintenance here!

Comment: still. is there a way to return object right after or I have to return observable of object?

Comment: Well, most endpoints in Angular return an observable which you do have to subscribe to resolve them. How is my update?

Comment: .pipe does not exist on AngularFireStoreDocument...

And yes. exactly. I want to return user without observable. 

How to make that service do that?

Comment: Hmm I'm not 100% sure how Firbase does it but I updated my code there. It appears that the observable is coming from `.valueChanges()` so I inserted that before the pipe.